# Can´t scroll ion-card in Ionic 2

Tags: scroll, ionic2

I've got a component in Ionic 2 which displays some profile which does not fit in the screen, and for some reason it's not scrolling.

I read that not all elements have scroll, but in this case I'm wrapping everything inside an ion-content, so I guess this should work.

What am I missing here?
Thanks.

```
<ion-header>
      <app-header></app-header>
    </ion-header>

    <ion-content>
      <ion-card>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-avatar>
            <img src="assets/avatar.png">
          </ion-avatar>
          <h2>{{user.firstname}} {{user.lastname}}</h2>
          <p>{{user.email}}</p>
        </ion-item>

        <img src="assets/avatar.png"/>

        <ion-card-content>
          <ion-list>
            <button ion-item [navPush]="accountSettings">Account Settings</button>
            <ion-item>Ranking</ion-item>
            <ion-item>
              <h3>Statistics</h3>
              <p>some_info_about_stats</p>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item>Badges</ion-item>
          </ion-list>
        </ion-card-content>
      </ion-card>
    </ion-content>
```

Comment: Do you have any error in console? i test you code and it is scrolling well!

Comment: Sorry, it's working now, I don´t really know why it was not working before.